# Ember: get target url from afterModel

Tags: ember.js

I have two paths pointing to the same route:

```
this.route('items', { path: ':fruitName/rotten' });
this.route('items', { path: ':fruitName' });
```

I am trying to get the current URL from within the afterModel hook of the /items/fruitName route. If I use this.get('router.url'), it will give me the previous URL before the transition. I need to detect if the target has 'rotten' at the end of the path.

I found that transition.intent.url has the path as a string, but only when its manually entered into the browser. If I click a link to transtion, transition.intent.url is undefined.

How can I determine if the transition URL is /items/fruitName/ or /items/FruitName/rotten?

Comment: the obvious question: why just don't use the same route twice?

Comment: @Lux, I have two tabs on my page and I need to target them with the paths defined above. I also do not want to use query params as my site uses all url params and it would be an irregularity.

Comment: but why do you use the same route for both tabs? Just use two routes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before determine which url you have, my question is : how do you make a transition with a different url to the same route (by using `{{link-to}}`) ?

In your case, you have the same route for 2 different purpose, I understand what you want to accomplish but you will break ember rules (which force you to make a bad design).

You can accomplish what you want to do by using **nested routes**. let me explain:

`/:fruitName` and `/:fruitName/rotten` have the same base (same data): a page for a fruit but in the rotten route, you want to display in another tab.

It's a design problem not a route problem, you can make the most of nested route to:

- use index to display main content
- subroute to display other thing

you can check an [example here](https://ember-twiddle.com/ea87caac9e7e86fe55ae2e531f843f57?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) with a basic css tab.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use queryParams for this?  So your URL would look something like this:

`items/tomato?rotten=false` 
or perhaps you want to go with something more generic:

`items/tomato?state=rotten`

The route and controller will be set up something like what can be found here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/query-params/

Comment: The rest of my site uses all url params, so it would be an irregularity that I do not want to add in.